# How does this AJAX script pass a variable via post to the PHP script?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am going through this tutorial

http://www.9lessons.info/2009/04/exactly-twitter-like-follow-and-remove.html

on how to implement a twitter-like follow/unfollow button.

I am also completely new to AJAX and so I am kind of figuring it out as I go along.

Usually one passes variables through a form and sets the action to POST and then does stuff with PHP.

Here however, there is this section of javascript (for following a user)

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
$(function() 
{
    $(".follow").click(function(){
        var element = $(this);
        var I = element.attr("id");
        var info = 'id=' + I;
        $("#loading").html('<img src="loader.gif" >');

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "follow.php",
            data: info,
            success: function(){
                $("#loading").ajaxComplete(function(){}).slideUp();
                $('#follow'+I).fadeOut(200).hide();
                $('#remove'+I).fadeIn(200).show();
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

and  say we have this section of html/php

```
<?php
$sql=mysql_query("Some SQL Statement that grabs users");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
    $id=$row["user_id"];
?>
<div id="follow<?php echo $id;?>">
    <a href="#" class="follow" id="<?php echo $id;?>">
    <span class="follow_b"> Follow </span></a>
</div>
<div id="remove<?php echo $id;?>" style="display:none"> 
    You Following <a href="#" class="remove" id="<?php echo $id;?>">
    <span class="remove_b"> remove </span></a>
</div>
<?php
}
?>
```

What is the POST variable needed by follow.php called? What does "success" do and how does it interact with follow.php?

Comment: basically it passes the `id` value from the button and then posts `id=value` to `follow.php` then on `success` runs the `poor example usage of a function` function, the whole tutorial is useless unless your given `follow.php` & `remove.php` which is not mentioned in the tut or given in the tut download example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP will receive a POST variable called 'id', which has the value that was stored in the page element with id `ID`.

The success handler is a script construct saying 'execute this code if the ajax request succeeded'. There's also an 'error' equivalent which only executes if something blew up. `success` by itself does not interact with PHP. It's simply some code that happens to be run if the PHP script does not return an error code.

Many ajax scripts indicate success/failure by manipulating the HTTP error code of the response. 2xx = everything ok, invoke the `success` handler. Anything 4xx or 5xx would invoke the `error` handler.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want $_POST['id'] to access your id parameter that was passed in.

"success" is called when your follow.php script completes successfully.

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery ajax call will encode data as a POST and send it to your PHP script. It seems like in this case the script is on the same page, so I'm guessing it will ping itself. AJAX does this asynchronously (by definition).

The success function is fired when the ajax receives a response from the php page. It's how you know the data has made the round trip, and any data you expect from the php script was received. This is where you would want to put whatever functionality comes next sequentially, or anything dependent on the data you're getting back from .php.

Answer (score 0):

This explains the parameters of the $.ajax() call: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

The post you included isn't a tutorial, it's simply a snippet of the code he uses. For actual tutorials of the Jquery Ajax function, try this tutorial:

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/5-ways-to-make-ajax-calls-with-jquery/